# How do I call a model in a custom Laravel 5.3 config file?

Tags: php, laravel, global-variables, config

I am trying to set global variable for my application.

I saw some suggestions and custom config file is one of them.

So i created a `constraints.php` file under config directory.

this is the sample code :

```
    return [
       'user_exist'=>1 
    ];
```

I can access this value using **config('constraints.user_exist')**

So i tried following code :

```
    return [
       'user_exist'=>count(\App\User::first())
    ];
```

But it throws following error :
**PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function connection() on null in** 
**project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 3308**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Step 1:** 
Example : Suppose you want to access user model in your config file then go to your config file and add following code in app.php

```
'user_model' => App\Models\User::class,
```

**Step2 :**
Now you can use this user_model in your application anywhere. Simply call

```
$user = config('app.user_model'); // app in file name
```

Now ,

1. Suppose you want to access all user data

> $user::all();

2. Suppose you want to access particular user data using user id

> $user::find(1);

Answer (score 2):

The application configuration is collected before Laravel bootstraps the database layer, so you don't have access to the underlying database collection at that point. You would be better to set this configuration variable after the application has loaded, perhaps in the `boot` method of your `AppServiceProvider`.

```
config(['constraints.user_exist', count(\App\User::first())])
```

Also, you could probably just do `\App\User::exists()` if you just want to check if any user models have been persisted to the database.

Comment: that makes sense! config('constraints.user_exist', count(\App\User::first())) is not working. Please see my answer. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, just edited the answer. As Doom5 said below, you pass the function an array of key/value pairs to set values.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Dwight answer , i can found my expected output by setting a new configuration variable in the **boot** method of **AppServiceProvider**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;


Config::set('user_exist', User::exists());
```

and accessing this value:

```
config('user_exist')
```

Comment: To use the `config()` helper to set the value of a configuration, pass a key/value pair to it: `config(['constraints.user_exist', count(\App\User::first())])`